# Prevent <ui:repeat> from being inserted in generated html

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I'm trying to combine JSF2.2 with bootstrap 3.2.0 components and got stuck when trying to use the button group with a dynamically generated list of labels. I traced the problem down to the ui:repeat tag being included in the generated html and thus preventing the correct css styling of bootstrap.

The xhtml code is:

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <ui:repeat var="role" value="#{editUserView.allRoles}">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">#{role.name}</button>
 </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

and the out put html is this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <ui:repeat><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Label1</button></ui:repeat>
 <ui:repeat><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Label2</button></ui:repeat>
 <ui:repeat><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Label3</button></ui:repeat>
 <ui:repeat><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Label4</button></ui:repeat>
 <ui:repeat><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Label5</button></ui:repeat>
</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent the JSF tag from the xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets namespace being printed in the generated html WITHOUT having to write custom components?

**Update**
Just for curiosity, the buttons are being displayed as normal buttons (with spacing in between them) and not as desired in the group button all together style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is recognizable as Mojarra [issue 2900](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2900) which was fixed in 2.2.2. It's currently [already](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/) at 2.2.8. So, just upgrading Mojarra to latest version should do.

That said, the `<ui:repeat>` is **not** a taghandler, but a true UI component. I fixed your question title. The `<c:forEach>` is a true taghandler. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) for the difference.